# How to properly use a scaler model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
X_train[:, :, 0] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[:, :, 0])
X_test[:, :, 0] = scaler.transform(X_test[:, :, 0])

X_train[:, :, 1] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[:, :, 1])
X_test[:, :, 1] = scaler.transform(X_test[:, :, 1])

X_train[:, :, 2] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[:, :, 2])
X_test[:, :, 2] = scaler.transform(X_test[:, :, 2])

X_train[:, :, 3] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[:, :, 3])
X_test[:, :, 3] = scaler.transform(X_test[:, :, 3])

X_train[:, :, 4] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[:, :, 4])
X_test[:, :, 4] = scaler.transform(X_test[:, :, 4])

scaler_filename = 'scaler.save'
joblib.dump(scaler, scaler_filename)
```

As you can see, I used MinMaxScaler to standardize each column of train/test data. After that, I saved the scaler object for posterior utilization. When I saved the scaler, can I just call the 'transform' method on the new data or do I have to call the 'fit' method too?

Comment: you should use pipelines. Additionally, the Scalers scale columns individually. As you are refitting the same object reference again and again you only retain your last scaler. I'd advise to just look at the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-scaler)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use different scalers for each of your 2D tables. Here, the scaler object you have at the end does not remember the scaling parameters for index 0. Maybe that is the desired behaviour though, tell me if I'm wrong...

If you saved the scaler object using joblib or pickle and load it from file again, it contains all the right parameters for later transformation so yes, you can use transform alone.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html):

> **MinMaxScaler**
>   Transforms features by scaling each feature to a given range.
>
> This estimator **scales and translates each feature individually** such
>   that it is in the given range on the training set, e.g. between zero
>   and one.

No Need to do that for each feature individually, you can scale multiple features at once:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test= scaler.transform(X_test)
```

I would also recommand to pickle your scaler using joblib:

```
import joblib

joblib.dump(scaler, 'scaler.save')
```

To load your scaler:

```
scaler = joblib.load('scaler.save')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MinMaxScaler` scales each column of data between 0 and 1. The correct way, from a machine learning point of view, is to "learn" a scaler on the training data, and then use the learned scaler on testing data. The reason for this is two fold

1. We are assuming your training data is large and varied enough to capture the maximum and minimum values within the entire dataset (train and test)
2. The test set is assumed to be unknown / unseen. You would apply scaling to test data in "real time" as it becomes available, and therefore you do not need to (or sometimes cannot even) train a scaler every time a new test data point becomes available

I would use it as such

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pickle

scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)  # learn a scaler on all columns of X_train
# now transform the training and testing data using the learned scaler
x_scaled_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
x_scaled_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

pickle.dump(scaler, open("scaler.pkl", "wb"))  # save learned scaler
```